# Two legend styles for two stacked chart styles in highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have two types of charts in a highchart, one of a **column** type and another of a **line** type (they have their own series). So I want the legends for the two different charts (line and column) to have two different locations, one  at bottom left and another at bottom right. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like highcharts supports two legends using the legend attribute. However, it does support labels, which you can place anywhere on the chart. It's  more fiddly, but you can use them to render your own labels wherever you want.

A basic example would be:

```
      labels: {
        items: [{
            html: "Legend 1",
            style: {
                top: '10px',
                left: '20px',
                height: '30px'
            }
        }, {
            html: "Legend 2",
            style: {
                top: '10px',
                left: '120px',
                height: '30px'
            }
        }]
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PRKr/

You will have to do some maths to calculate their positions within your plot area, and you will have to do some work to make them look nice (using standard html and css attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this option is not supported, but you can use append to add amount of divs as series, and catch click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/8JB6h/

```
$.each(chart.series, function (i, serie) {

            $('body').append('<div class="legend" id="serie' + i + '">' + serie.name + '</div>');


        });

        $('.legend').click(function () {
            var tmpserie = chart.get($(this).attr('id'));
            if (tmpserie.visible) tmpserie.hide();
            else tmpserie.show();

        });
```